# How can I define local environment variables in android studio?

Tags: android, git, version-control, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I and a few colleagues are building an app and using git for version control.

Our app utilized the Google Maps Api, which generates unique api keys based on SHA1 certificates. To utilize maps, the api key must be referenced in the manifest as such

```
    ....

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="api_key_goes_here"/>

</application>
```

We've each generated our own api keys based on builds of the app on our personal machines, but we'd like to have a properties file on each of our machines not checked into version control which stores our unique api key so we don't have to manually change the api key in the manifest each time we pull from the repository.

Is this possible? I know there are properties files in android studio but I haven't a clue how to use them, especially in this case.

EDIT:

Full manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".Application">
    <activity android:name="com.misfiremedia.parseexperiment.app.DispatchActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.misfiremedia.parseexperiment.app.SignUpActivity">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.misfiremedia.parseexperiment.app.WelcomeActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".EmailLogInActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.misfiremedia.parseexperiment.app.HomeActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.misfiremedia.parseexperiment.app.home.PostLocationActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".NewPostActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="THIS_IS_THE_KEY_WE_NEEDED_TO_HAVE_DIFFERENT"/>
</application>
```

Comment: I think a better approach would be to use your build system to insert the property into your manifest file (no IDE dependency).

Comment: @jangroth sounds fine. Would you be able to point me in the right direction for doing such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

In Android there is a concept of buildTypes, so what you can do create three buildTypes or how many you are required in your team.

Like one, two and three as shown in picture below with three different manifests which all has different keys in each.

[image]

Now team memebers can choose their respective buildVariant and work, selected buildVariant doesnt have any affect when someone takes pull from git, it maintain the selection.

Comment: Tried getting this to work but I'm getting issues like "Manifest Merger Failed" when I try building the variant with an api key different than the one in the main manifest. And if I switch to the variant with the api key same as the main manifest, it tells me the apk is unsigned. I've played with the settings in the project structure dialog box but still can't get anything to work as it should.

Comment: can you please include your exact Manifests so I can try in my environment.

Comment: I just edited. 

Also, I discovered we could add multiple SHA1 certificates to a single api key so technically this is a non-issue now.